# How to make this code execute faster?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
def lookfor(alist, number):
  if number in alist:
    return alist.index(number)
  else:
    return "no"
```

So basically I input hundreds of thousands of numbers and I have to send each one of them thorugh "lookfor" to get an output of either the index of "number" in "alist" or get"no" if the number isn't there.
It perfectly computes when I input not as many numbers but takes several minutes when I input xx,xxx-xxx,xxx numbers.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a question better suited for <codereview.stackexchange.com>

Comment: Have you tried sorting and binary searching? Bar the initial O(n*log(n)) sort time, this brings search down to O(log(n)) which is much faster than linear `in`...

Comment: You're scanning your list twice (`number in alist` checks once, `alist.index` has to scan again).  You could possibly benefit from the use of a `set`, though they're inherently unordered.  You could also use `enumerate` to get it in the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

Your code iterates through the list until it finds the number you seek (or until it reaches the end), and if it does find the number, it has to iterate the exact same amount to return the index. Why not take advantage of the behavior of the `.index` method? Just keep in mind that it raises a `ValueError` if the number is not present in the list.

```
def lookfor(alist, number):
    try:
        return alist.index(number)
    except ValueError:
        return "no"
```

afterword: use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module to find the most efficient solution, but be sure to use a variety of inputs so that you can find the overall fastest solution.

Comment: Hey, this method seems to work a little faster but still takes minutes to compute a larger amount of numbers :(

Comment: @kiasy let's try constructing a large dataset in Python, shall we? `>>> [1]*100000000 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    [1]*100000000
MemoryError` oops. Computers have limitations (it took me a minute to run into that error)

Comment: The goal is to run the whole program within a second. I was thinking binary search, would that work

Comment: @kiasy As pointed out in another answer I may have misunderstood your use case. Are you invoking `lookfor` repeatedly, or is your dataset just very large?

Comment: @kiasy Ok, then do as the others suggested and construct a dictionary, which will require one iteration through your dataset and then nothing more. A binary search would be inappropriate here because your data may not be sorted, and even if it is, a binary search takes `O(log n)` iterations for each execution, which is still expensive compared to the dictionary approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently needs to search through the entire list for each call to `lookfor`. This can be very slow if `alist` is big enough.

Instead, you should create a dictionary that maps each element to its index in `alist`. For example, for `alist = [7,4,88]`, you'd have: `indexmap = {7:0, 4:1, 88:2}`. Then you can search the dictionary with:

```
def lookfor(indexmap, number):
    return indexmap.get(number, "no")
```

If `alist` is constant, you can create `indexmap` during initialization:

```
indexmap = {number: index for index,number in enumerate(alist)}
```

If `alist` changes over time, you can maintain this dictionary together with `alist`. For example, if you normally add items with `append`, you can use:

```
alist.append(number)
if number not in indexmap:
    indexmap[number] = len(alist) - 1
```

Comment: Why would OP do this? It requires `n` iterations, and uses extra memory unnecessarily.

Comment: @2rs2ts Because searching in a list is O(n) while searching in a dict is O(1). It can be a huge difference, depending on the size of the list.

Comment: If OP was trying to call this function with several different sought values, sure. But that is not how to speed up that snippet of code; that is implementing a different solution altogether.

Comment: @2rs2ts Sorry but you're wrong. OP *is* calling this function with several different values (hundreds of thousands of them according to the question), and this is a solution to exactly what OP is doing.

Comment: He's talking about his data set, not the number of invocations of his function.

Comment: @2rs2ts The question clearly says that he calls `lookfor` hundreds of thousands of times ("I have to send each one of them thorugh "lookfor" to get an output of either the index of "number" in "alist" or get"no"")

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right. But I wouldn't say it's particularly clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
def index_on(lst):
    index = {val:i for i,val in enumerate(lst)}
    def lookup(val):
        return index.get(val, 'no')
    return lookup

search = index_on(alist)

search('123-4567')   # => 293   (index in alist)
search('123-4500')   # => 'no'  (not found)
```